# Creating user image pattern, identicon, of stackoverflow.com

Tags: r, image, plot, identicon

Users of stackoverflow.com who do not upload their photos have an image pattern in their photo area. These are simple but different for all users and that is very impressive. Each one has a central square and outer border, both are usually filled with patterns. Is the code for making these image patterns available or how can they be created? Can they be created in R?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415/decode-email-address-from-gravatar-hash

Comment: There's some info and php source [here](http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/wp_identicon/)

Comment: I do not know the code used, but if there is a library of small symbols in `R`, perhaps associated with `plot`, you could probably create an identicon using 16 of those symbols and one or two rules to govern symmetry.  I have not tried it.  This would make a good `Code Golf` puzzle.

Comment: I had a bit of a play with this [gist here](https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/c0b90ab1d6a29599359a) - the randomisation is greatly simplified (in part because of R's restrictions on seed size), so it won't generate identicons identical to the Gravatar service.

Answer (score 7):

Compute a hash of the email address with package `digest`:

```
d <- digest('ab@c.com', algo='md5', serialize=FALSE)
d
## [1] "b1554c62bf1d05a4a9c48754a6619c17"
```

Then ask gravatar for the image:

```
download.file(paste0('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/', d, '.png?d=identicon'), mode='wb', destfile='ab.png')
## trying URL 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b1554c62bf1d05a4a9c48754a6619c17.png?d=identicon'
## Content type 'image/png' length 2280 bytes
## opened URL
## ==================================================
## downloaded 2280 bytes
```

[image]

The `mode='wb'` is required for Windows systems.  `mode='w'` is the default, and the `b` flag is ignored on non-Windows systems.

Comment: But what could be the programming code to create these kind of patterns?

Comment: For example, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon